# Magento 1.9: How to fix Amazon Extension with Allowed JavaScript Origins issue?

Tags: magento-1.9, amazon-payment

```
Error Summary
400 Bad Request
The domain on which you are using the JavaScript SDK has not been whitelisted for your application. Please add your website domain in the 'Allowed JavaScript Origins' section under 'Web Settings' on the Amazon Seller Central App Console for Login with Amazon.
```

I have added my website url to the Allowed JavaScript Origins but it says it is not yet allowed. so who has any solution that can help me? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's exactly the right URL? For instance, example.com is not the same as www.example.com. The root part of the URL must be identical for whitelisting and actual URL.

In case that you have created multiple applications in Seller Central, you need to make sure to use the right client ID as each application can have a different whitelisting.